# How to add a new button to the button bar in Total Commander for Android?

Tags: file-management

I got Total Commander on my Android phone.

I need to check the directory size for a folder and the solution is:

[Add a new button to the button bar, and then](https://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?t=40283)..

I understand that but my question is how to add a new button to the button bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tap on icon (arrow). You get a **+**, add details as per link - you can see the button with KB, on the first line

[image]

Comment: Screenshot refers to the bottom portion on opening app. Pasted only relevant portion